# Laravel project with bitbucket pipeline on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm currently setting up a pipeline (FYI, I'm completely new to CD/CI) in Bitbucket for my Laravel project, that should automatically deploy my latest build of my master branch to my website. Because the server doesn't have composer installed I cannot install the dependencies or deploy the migrations that my project needs.

Is it possible to build the entire project using the pipeline and move it completely over the server using something like `git-ftp`? Below my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file.

```
image: php:7.2-fpm

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip gnupg ssh
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
          - apt-get install -y nodejs
          - npm install
          - npm run production
          - php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.pipelines', '.env');"
          - composer dump-autoload
          - php artisan key:generate
          - php artisan migrate
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST_PATH_P
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is as follows.

I've skipped the use of pipelines and removed the exclusion of the `./vendor` folder from my `.gitignore` file. I've created a subdomain with git support, allowing me to pull and deploy my development branch. Did the same for my production/master branch.

Comment: Did you modify your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`? Because I am in a similar situation and want to upload my Laravel/Vue project to a shared hosting